# How to extract secrets from running node app via debugger

Tags: node.js, express, security, nestjs, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to hack my own node app and extract secrets from it by attaching a debugger to the running process. It's a NestJS / Express app.
So there is a compiled main.ts file of the same form as [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#:%7E:text=The%20main.ts%20includes%20an%20async%20function%2C%20which%20will%20bootstrap%20our%20application%3A) running.

I am attaching a debugger via `node inspect -p $PID`. I can now go into a repl, but from there I don't know how to access the instantiated NestJS objects...
There is a ConfigService class from which I would like to retrieve the variables.

How would I continue here?